# How to import many files into SharePoint Online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, file-upload

I have a lot of PDF files in my local storage that should be submitted to the SharePoint Online document library.
Is there only a way to drag and drop it into the destination document library?
Is there a more efficient and safer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jerry's suggestion is the simplest solution. Be aware that the uploaded PDF files all get a fresh creation and modification date. There is also no extraction of PDF metadata (e.g. keywords). The pdf files also get assigned the default content type (probably document).
There is no support for adding custom metadata.

If you want these advanced features then look into other options:

- PowerShell scripts
- SPMT (free)
- 3rd party migration tools (not free)

Paul | SLIM Applications

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you tell me if you have any links related to those 3 your suggestions?

Comment: PowerShell
e.g.
https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/upload-document-using-powershell-https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115834/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-document-library-and-updateing-column-fields-using/277555#277555


SPMT
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool


3rd party tools
https://directory.collab365.community/office365-sharepoint/best-sharepoint-migration-tools/
Most tools are client/server based but there are also browser-based tools.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps me.

Answer (score 1):

For uploading files to SharePoint library, you can use the upload button, it can directly upload a folder to library.

And for more information about uploading, you can check this:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/upload-files-and-folders-to-a-library-da549fb1-1fcb-4167-87d0-4693e93cb7a0

[image]